# Django channels load previous messages

Tags: django, django-channels

I am in the process of building a simple chat application and have already managed to make a functioning chat that stores sent messages in a model. However, I am struggling to retrieve previous messages.

```
consumers.py
def old_messages(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        room = ChatRoom.objects.get(room_name=self.room_name)
        messages = ChatMessage.objects.filter(room=room)
        content = {
            'command': 'old'
        }
        return content
```

```
room.html

      chatSocket.onopen = function(e) {
      console.log("open",e)
      old_messages()
      };

      function old_messages() {
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
          'command': 'old_messages'
        }));
      };
       chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
          const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
          document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (data.message + '\n');
      };

      document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
          const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
          const message = messageInputDom.value;
          chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
              'message': message,
              'command': 'fetch_messages'
          }));
          messageInputDom.value = '';
      };
```

Whenever I call old_messages() I get the error message = text_data_json['message']
KeyError: 'message' which refers to this chunk of code

```
def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
```

Comment: So where does the key  `message` come from, in `text_data_json['message']` come from? The JSON you send from the front has no `message` key in it

Comment: It comes from `document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) { const messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input'); const message = messageInputDom.value; chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({ 'message': message,'command': 'fetch_messages' }));messageInputDom.value = '';};` and the wierd thing is that there is no key error when I don't call old_messages()

Comment: Please add the detail to the code in your question. The error message says that the key `message` isn't found in the data sent. So it is important to add the part of the code where you send the data with key `message` in the question

Comment: I added it to my original post. I also found out that the cause for the error is that text_data_json in receive gets 'command' and 'old' while looking for 'message'.

Comment: You are sending a JSON like this `{'command': 'old_messages'}` from the front and expecting a `message` key in the back. That's the problem

Comment: Right, but how do I send a JSON from the front that will call the `old_messages` function in my consumer without calling the receive function. Otherwise is there a way to have an if statement in receive that calls `old_messages` without looking for the `message` key?